# How can upgrade my expo app android api level

Tags: android, react-native, expo

My expo app SDK level is 42.0.5. I am trying to upgrade the app's Android API level 33. How can I do this easily? I tried to use build properties but It doesn't work. I tried to deploy my app but still, my Android level was 28. I think my expo SDK level is not enough for this package.